# How could I generate this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am curious how what function will map in the following way:

$$ 0 \to 1$$
$$ 1 \to 4$$
$$ 2 \to 7$$
$$ 3 \to 10$$
$$ 4 \to 13$$

etc.

I have been playing around trying to find a function for a bit now. 
I know that I can use:
$$f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$$

$$ x \implies f(x)=3x-2$$

However, this shifts my inputs and omits zero as an input.

Also, I am hoping for more than an answer. I would like to get better at finding these sorts of sequences myself incase I need this skill later. So please give detail on how you determined a solution/approached the problem etc.

Comment: Is $f(1)=3\cdot 1-2$?

Comment: $f(x)=3x+1$ works.

Comment: Oh woops! Let me edit this. I wrote in the wrong function.

Comment: This is an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: oeis.org is the best resource for this sort of question

Comment: oh man. So obvious.

Comment: I thought it was a joke.

Comment: no skill required, lagrange interpolation is all is needed.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=3x+1$ works.

You may want to learn about finite differences and [Newton's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton.27s_series).
See examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1046785/589), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98009/589) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68810/589). The bottom line is that polynomials can be seen as higher-order arithmetic progressions.

For your data, you'd get:
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 4 & 7 & 10 & 13\\
3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
$$
Assuming that $3$'s in the second row of repeat forever, we get the formula
$$
f(n)=1 \binom{n}{0} + 3 \binom{n}{1} = 1+3n
$$

Answer (score 2):

For this sequence, notice that 1, 4, 7... are an arithmetic sequence with difference of 3. So, if you plot the points on a graph, you will get a line with slope 3. The standard form of any line is y = mx+b. In this case m = 3. So, you need to solve for b. Plugging in (0,1) gives you b is 1. Therefore, the line is y = 3x+1. Hence , the sequence is 3x+1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!